# Calling a mapping with array of struct. Optimization or performance recommendation?

Tags: arrays, mapping, struct, optimization

I have a struct that has a number of fields and a mapping of `StudentInfo` array.

```
struct StudentInfo {    
    uint studentId;
    uint courseId;
    uint age;
    string firstName; 
    string lastName; 
    string gender;         
    bool hasPassed;          
}

mapping(address => StudentInfo[]) public studentInfo;
```

Basically, a teacher can retrieve his/her list of `studentInfo`.

A new student info can be saved into `studentInfo` state variable via the function below:

```
function storeStudent(uint _studentId, uint _courseId, uint age, string _firstName, string _lastName, string gender) public returns (bool) {  
    studentInfo[msg.sender].push(StudentInfo(_studentId, _courseId, age, _firstName, _lastName, gender, 0));                
}
```

and when the teacher needs to retrieve the list of studentInfo, I call it like below:

```
function getStudentInfo(address _teacher) public view returns (uint[], uint[], uint[]) {
    uint length = studentInfo[_teacher].length;
    uint[] memory studentId = new uint[](length);
    uint[] memory courseId = new uint[](length);
    uint[] memory age = new uint[](length);   

    for (uint i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        studentId[i] = studentInfo[_teacher][i].studentId;
        courseId[i] = studentInfo[_teacher][i].courseId;
        age[i] = studentInfo[_teacher][i].age;
    }

    return (studentId, courseId, age);
}

function getStudentInfo2(address _teacher) public view returns (string[], string[], string[], bool[]) {
    uint length = studentInfo[_teacher].length;  
    string[] memory firstName = new string[](length);
    string[] memory lastName = new string[](length);
    string[] memory gender = new string[](length);
    bool[] memory hasPassed = new bool[](length);

    for (uint i = 0; i < length; i++) {     
        firstName [i] = studentInfo[_teacher][i].firstName ;
        lastName [i] = studentInfo[_teacher][i].lastName ;
        gender [i] = studentInfo[_teacher][i].gender ;
        hasPassed [i] = studentInfo[_teacher][i].hasPassed ;
    }

    return (firstName, lastName, gender, hasPassed);
}
```

Those functions are working, but I'm just wondering if there could be any performance or gas (runs out) related issues if the size of `studentInfo` gets bigger and bigger.

Can the above logics be optimized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid the loop by having a mapping of struct instead of a mapping of arrays of structs.

Then the struct will contain arrays for each parameter:

```
mapping(address => StudentInfo) public studentInfo;

struct StudentInfo {    
    uint[] studentId;
    uint[] courseId;
    uint[] age;
    string[] firstName; 
    string[] lastName; 
    string[] gender;         
    bool[] hasPassed;          
}
```

You can get, for instance, all the first names in one shot doing:

```
studentInfo['teacherAddress'].fristName
```

Same for the other parameters

Hope this helps